# RichFaces 4.5.14 Failed to define class org.richfaces.renderkit

Tags: richfaces, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2, mojarra, seam2

I'm using Jboss 7.1; Seam 2.3; JDK 1.7; and JSF 2.2 and RichFaces 4.5.14.

When i start for the first time to deploy the Seam empty web projet, i got that error :

[image]

My Java build path :

[image]

and the project ...\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib :

[image]

and the stackTrace :

> 12:07:39,001 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) Could not load class designated by HandlesTypes
>   [org.richfaces.renderkit.PlaceholderRendererBase]:
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.PlaceholderRendererBase from [Module
>   "deployment.logement_2016.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>   12:07:39,001 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed
>   to define class org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolbarRendererBase in
>   Module "deployment.logement_2016.war:main" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.VerifyError: class
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolbarRendererBase overrides final
>   method
>   encodeChildren.(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)V
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:229)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>
> 12:07:39,017 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed
>   to define class org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolbarGroupRenderer in
>   Module "deployment.logement_2016.war:main" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link
>   org/richfaces/renderkit/html/ToolbarGroupRenderer (Module
>   "deployment.logement_2016.war:main" from Service Module Loader)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:229)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/richfaces/renderkit/html/ToolbarRendererBase  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  ... 16 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolbarRendererBase from [Module
>   "deployment.logement_2016.war:main" from Service Module Loader]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  ... 21 more

Thanks for HELP.

Comment: Please add on your question the actual stacktrace instead of an image. It will be easier to understand you problem. A stackTrace is not only one error it is a trace and to understand it we have to follow it.

Comment: You're mixing RichFaces 4.3 with 4.5, get rid of the old jars.

Answer (score 0):

You have old RichFaces jars in your classpath. Make sure you only have RichFaces 4.5.14.Final.

As of 4.5.14.Final there is no `encodeChildren` method anymore in `ToolbarRendererBase`.